# Using DSolve with a boundary condition at -Infinity

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I would like to solve a simple 2nd-order ODE with one of the boundary conditions defined at $ -\infty $. The ODE I am looking to solve is:

$$ w''(z)-2i\pi^2w(z)=0 $$

with the corresponding boundary conditions:

$$ w(z=-\infty)=0, \; w'(z=0)=0+i\dfrac{\tau_{0}}{\mu}. $$

My attempt at a solution using `DSolve` is as follows:

```
DSolve[{-2 I \[Pi]^2 w[z] + (w^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z] == 0, 
w[-Infinity] == 0, w'[0] == 0 + I Subscript[\[Tau], 0]/\[Mu]}, w[z],z]
```

but I only get an empty set of curly brackets as an output. I checked the rest of my snipet of code without the `w[-Infinity]==0` boundary condition, and that works as expected; therefore, I know that this is a problem with the boundary condition at $z=-\infty$. I am looking for methods with which I can solve simple ODE's with boundary conditions at infinity, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the boundary condition at z=0 a condition on `w` or on `w'`?  You have it both ways.

Comment: The boundary condition at z=0 is for w'. I am sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the solution of your equation without the boundary conditions:

```
sol = DSolve[-2 I \[Pi]^2 w[z] + w''[z] == 0, w[z], z] // ExpToTrig //
   ComplexExpand

(*  {{w[z] -> 
   C[1] Cos[\[Pi] z] Cosh[\[Pi] z] + C[2] Cos[\[Pi] z] Cosh[\[Pi] z] +
     C[1] Cos[\[Pi] z] Sinh[\[Pi] z] - C[2] Cos[\[Pi] z] Sinh[\[Pi] z] + 
    I (C[1] Cosh[\[Pi] z] Sin[\[Pi] z] - C[2] Cosh[\[Pi] z] Sin[\[Pi] z] + 
       C[1] Sin[\[Pi] z] Sinh[\[Pi] z] + C[2] Sin[\[Pi] z] Sinh[\[Pi] z])}}  *)
```

Now let us take its limit at `z->-Infinity`:

```
Limit[w[z] /. sol, z -> -\[Infinity]]

(* {ComplexInfinity}  *)
```

Let us now try this limit at `C[1]=0` and `C[2]=0`:

```
Limit[w[z] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 0}, z -> -\[Infinity]]

(* ComplexInfinity *)

Limit[w[z] /. sol /. {C[2] -> 0}, z -> -\[Infinity]]

(*  0  *)
```

The latter gives us what we need, therefore, `C[2]=0`.

Let us now implement the second boundary condition:

```
    Solve[(D[(w[z] /. sol /. C[2] -> 0), z] /. z -> 0) == I*t/m, C[1]]

(*  {{C[1] -> ((1/2 + I/2) t)/(m \[Pi])}}  *)
```

Done. Have fun!

Comment: Nice post. I have not see you in a while, I hope you are all good. Regards.

Comment: @user21 Thank you, I am fine.

Comment: What if some linear combination of the coefficients is zero, but both `C[1]`and `C[2]` are non-zero? Then you can't find the solution by testing simple cases. In this particular problem we are lucky: the correct boundary condition at infinity is `C[2]==0` instead of `Pi C[1]-7C[2]==0` or something.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta With `sol = w[z] /. DSolve[-2 I \[Pi]^2 w[z] + w''[z] == 0, w[z], z][[1]]'` check how does `List @@ sol` look like and the perform `Limit[#, z -> -Infinity] & /@ List @@ sol` - this explains why `C[2]=0` and gives a _hint_ how to proceed with less trivial cases.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta In the case you mentioned one needs to invent an approach. It is exactly the point, where science turns into art.

Answer (score 2):

This method is somewhat similar to [Alexei](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/788/alexei-boulbitch)'s. We first solve the equation with the boundary condition (b.c.) at `0` i.e. the b.c. `DSolve` can handle:

```
generalsol = 
 DSolve[{-2 I π^2 w[z] + w''[z] == 0, w'[0] == 0 + (I Subscript[τ, 0])/μ}, 
   w[z], z][[1, 1, -1]]

(* ((1/2 - I/2) E^((-1 - 
I) π z) ((1 + I) π μ C[1] + (1 + I) E^((2 + 2 I) π z) π μ C[
 1] - I Subscript[τ, 0]))/(π μ) *)
```

This solution involves `E^((-1 - I) π z)`, which shouldn't exist in a solution that goes to `0` at `-Infinity`, so coefficient of `E^((-1 - I) π z)` should be `0`. To make the coefficient clearer, let's `Collect`:

```
Collect[generalsol, Exp[_], Simplify]
(* E^((1 + I) π z) C[1] + 
 E^((-1 - I) π z) (C[1] - ((1/2 + I/2) Subscript[τ, 0])/(π μ)) *)
```

Apparently, `C[1] - ((1/2 + I/2) Subscript[τ, 0])/(π μ)` should be equal to `0`, so the particular solution satisfies the b.c. at `-Infinity` is:

```
sol = Function[z, #] &[
  E^((1 + I) π z) C[1] /. C[1] -> ((1/2 + I/2) Subscript[τ, 0])/(π μ)]

(* Check: *)
{-2 I π^2 w[z] + w''[z] == 0, w[-∞] == 0, 
   w'[0] == 0 + (I Subscript[τ, 0])/μ} /. w -> sol // Simplify
(* {True, True, True} *)
```