# Find the arbitrary functions of integration of a PDE

Tags: differential-equations

The PDE in question is,

```
sol = DSolve[{epsilon^2*D[u[eta, zeta], eta, eta] + 
      D[u[eta, zeta], zeta, zeta] == -1}, u, {eta, zeta}]
```

[image]

`DSolve` is unable to find `C[1]` and `C[2]` with the following boundary conditions,

```
bc1 = 2*Kn*epsilon*(D[u[eta, zeta], eta] /. eta -> 1) == -u[eta, zeta];
bc2 = 2*Kn*epsilon*(D[u[eta, zeta], zeta] /. zeta -> 1) == -u[eta, zeta];
bc3 = D[u[eta, zeta], eta] == 0 /. eta -> 0
bc4 = D[u[eta, zeta], zeta] == 0 /. zeta -> 0
```

Is there an alternate way to find `C[1]` and `C[2]` subject to the above conditions?

Comment: …I think the `/. eta -> 1` should be at the end of the equation i.e. `2*Kn*epsilon*(D[u[eta, zeta], eta] ) == -u[eta, zeta]/. eta -> 1`?

Comment: @xzczd Any suggestion on how to get a particular solution for this PDE?

Comment: Do this system have a finite b.c. at $\infty$ or $-\infty$? If so, the method mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130830/1871) will probably work.

Comment: @xzczd The issue is that geometry of the physical model is finite. So we can't have b.c at $\pm\infty$

Comment: Then we need 2 more b.c.s, or we can't determine a particular solution.

Comment: @xzczd I have included the missing b.cs. This is the same question for which you guyz (user21 and you) helped me with the numerical solution.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147089/how-to-input-robin-boundary-conditions-for-nonstandard-laplace-equation