# Solve the heat equation for a semi infinite rod considering convection

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, boundary-condition-at-infinity

**Bug introduced in or after 10.3, persisting through 11.2.**

---

I'm trying to solve following PDE (heat equation):

$$ \begin{cases} u_t = a \, u_{xx} \\ u(x,0) = 0\\ \lim_{x\to \infty}u(x,t) =0\\
\alpha\, (\theta_0-u(0,t))+\dot{q}_0=-\lambda u_x(0,t)  \end{cases}$$

Where basically I have an initial temperature of $0$ everywhere, a constant heat flux at the beginning of the rod, and convection between air and the rod at its beginning ($\theta_0$ is the air temperature which is assumed to be constant).

I found following analytical solution for the problem:

$$u(x,t) = \frac{\dot{q}_0+\alpha \, \theta_0}{\alpha}\left[ \mathrm{erfc}\, \left(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{a \, t}} \right) -\mathrm{exp}\,\left(\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}x+a \frac{\alpha^2}{\lambda^2}t \right)\mathrm{erfc}\,\left(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{a\, t}} + \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \sqrt{a\, t} \right) \right] $$

which is physically meaningful. With mathematica, however, I get some meaningless results, probably due to my not that  good mathematica skills.

This is what I tried to do:

```
λ = 0.8; c = 880; ρ = 1950; a = λ/(c ρ)
α = 15; θair = 0;

heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == a D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic1 = u[x, 0] == 0;
bc1 = α (θair - u[0, t]) + 650 == -λ Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t];

sol = DSolveValue[{heqn, ic1, bc1}, u[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1, 1]]
```

Which leads me to a complex solution (plotted below)

```
DensityPlot[sol, {t, 0, 2*3600}, {x, 0, 0.1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {t[s], x[m]}]
```

[image: Density plot of the resulting equation][[image: scale bar[2]]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol, {t, 3600, 7200, 3600}]], {x, 0, .1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x[m], θ[°C]}]
```

[image: Plot at t=1h and t=2h]

I'm aware of the fact that I didn't consider the condition at infinity. To do this, I tried to follow [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130817/using-dsolve-with-a-boundary-condition-at-infinity) without success. Also, mathematica finds the solution without this condition as soon as $\alpha = 0$.

---

This is the plot of the analytical solution I get:

```
Plot[{u[x, 600], u[x, 3600], u[x, 7200]}, {x, 0, .2}, Filling -> Axis, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x[m], θ[°C]}]
```

[image: Plot of analytical function]

Comment: Do you want to obtain the same analytic solution with _Mathematica_, or just want to solve the problem numerically or analytically?

Comment: BTW, something seems to be wrong with the $\LaTeX$ formula, I failed to reproduce the graph with it: `sola[t_, x_] = (
  q + α θair)/α (Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[a t])] - 
    Exp[α/λ x + a α^2/λ^2 t] Erfc[
      x/(2 Sqrt[α t]) + α/λ Sqrt[a t]])`

Comment: @xzczd at the moment I cannot check if I did some mistake by copying the analytical solution. I'll check it as soon as possible (probably in 1-2hours). Regarding your second question: I'm preparing a benchmark problem for a FEM simulation. A numerical solution is therefore in principle also ok. The only thing that seemed a bit strange to me is that Mathematica cannot solve a PDE which can be solved analytically (although I used Laplace transformations and this isn't probably the easiest thing for a software)

Comment: @xzczd The latex formula is correct, you had a small mistake in your definition of the term `Erfc[ x/(2 Sqrt[α t]) + α/λ Sqrt[a t]]`. It should be `x/(2 Sqrt[a t])` instead of `x/(2 Sqrt[α t])`.

Comment: Oh, I see… I suggest adding the _Mathematica_ code for the formula to the question so people can easily test it. BTW, thx for accepting, but you actually don't need to accept that fast, you can wait for 24 hours or so to see if someone will come up with a better answer :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Semi-analytic Solution

The approach in the linked post can be used for solving your problem analytically. We just need an extra step i.e. making Laplace transform:

```
Clear@"`*"
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == a D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic1 = u[x, 0] == 0;
ic2 = α (θair - u[0, t]) + q == -λ Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t];

teqn = LaplaceTransform[{heqn, ic2}, t, s] /. Rule @@ ic1 /. 
  HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsol = Collect[u[x, t] /. First@DSolve[teqn, u[x, t], x], Exp[_], Simplify]
(*
E^((Sqrt[s] x)/Sqrt[a]) C[1] + (E^(-((Sqrt[s] x)/Sqrt[
   a])) (s^(3/2) λ C[1] + Sqrt[a] (q + α (θair - s C[1]))))/(
 Sqrt[a] s α + s^(3/2) λ)
*)
```

`tsol` is the transformed solution, with one constant to be determined. Since the solution should vanish at $\infty$, `C[1]` can only be `0`:

```
tsolfunc[s_, x_] = tsol /. C[1] -> 0
```

The last step is to transform back, but sadly `InverseLaplaceTransform` can't handle it. Nevertheless, we've indeed obtained an analytic solution involving integration:
$$
u=\frac{1}{2 \pi i } \int_{\gamma-i \infty }^{\gamma+i \infty } \frac{\sqrt{a} e^{-\frac{\sqrt{s} x}{\sqrt{a}}} (\alpha \theta_0+q)}{\sqrt{a} \alpha  s+\lambda  s^{3/2}} e^{st} \, ds
$$

If we want to get the numeric result, we need to make use of numeric inverse Laplace transform package e.g. [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/):

```
λ = 8/10; c = 880; ρ = 1950; a = λ/(c ρ);
α = 15; θair = 0; q = 650;
(* Definition of FT isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
Clear@sol; sol[t_, x_] = FT[tsolfunc[#, x] &, t];

Plot[sol[#, x] & /@ {600, 3600, 7200} // Evaluate, {x, 0, .2}, Filling -> Axis, 
 AxesLabel -> {x[m], θ[°C]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Analytic Solution

Based on this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163969/1871), the following is one way to find the symbolic Laplace inversion:

```
coe = (q + α θair);
mid = Apart[LaplaceTransform[tsolfunc[s, x]/coe, x, S] /. s -> sqrts^2] /. 
  sqrts -> Sqrt[s]

mid2 = InverseLaplaceTransform[mid, s, t]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {33.611455, Null} *)
final = FullSimplify[InverseLaplaceTransform[mid2[[1]] // Expand, S, x], {t > 0, a > 0}]
```

`coe final` is the analytic solution:

```
coe final
```

$$u=\frac{(\alpha  \theta_0+q)}{\alpha } \left(\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{a t}}\right)-e^{\frac{\alpha  (a \alpha  t+\lambda  x)}{\lambda ^2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{2 a \alpha  t+\lambda  x}{2 \lambda  \sqrt{a t}}\right)\right)$$

Check:

```
sola[t_, x_] = (q + α θair)/α (Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[a t])] - 
    Exp[α/λ x + a α^2/λ^2 t] Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[a t]) + α/λ Sqrt[a t]])

sola[t, x] == final coe // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

## Numeric Solution

`NDSolve` can also be used for solving the problem, of course. We just need to adjust the option a little:

```
inf = 0.2;

mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines",
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf, "ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

nsol = NDSolveValue[{heqn, ic1, ic2, u[inf, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, inf}, {t, 0, 7200}, 
   Method -> mol[True, 100]];

np = Plot[nsol[x, #] & /@ {600, 3600, 7200} // Evaluate, {x, 0, inf}, Filling -> Axis, 
  AxesLabel -> {x[m], θ[°C]}}]
```

The result looks the same so I'd like to omit it here. To learn more about why the option needs to be adjusted, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted it after getting the correct semi-analytical solution. However, now I'm trying the numerical one and I still get a `NDSolveValue::ibcinc` error (bc and ic are inconsistent), which, according to your other post should be avoided by using the method of lines.

Comment: @david Well, the linked post is not about avoiding `ibcinc`, it's about getting an accurate enough result even if it pops up. Notice `ibcinc` is merely a _warning_, it doesn't necessarily mean the result will be unreliable. （You can compare `np` to the analytic solution. ）

Comment: Sure, you're right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Analytical solution seems to be wrong!

Just try

```
heqn = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] == a Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t];
ic1 = u[x, 0] == 0;
ic2 = \[Alpha] (\[Theta]air - u[0, t]) +qp0 == -\[Lambda] Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t];

sol = DSolve [{heqn, ic1, ic2}, u[x, t], {x, t}][[1]] 
(*{u[x, t] -> -((\[Alpha] (qp0 + \[Alpha] \[Theta]air) ((2 \[Alpha] +x \[Lambda]) Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[a t])] - 
2 E^((\[Lambda] (x \[Alpha] +a t \[Lambda]))/\[Alpha]^2) \[Alpha] Erfc[(
    x \[Alpha] + 2 a t \[Lambda])/(2 Sqrt[a t] \[Alpha])]))/(2\[Lambda]^3))} *)
```

`sol` looks like the expected analytical solution!

`u[infinity,t]->0` seems to be fullfilled:

```
Simplify[Normal[ Series[u[x, t] /. sol, {x, Infinity, 0}] ], {x > 0,t > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Lambda] > 0, a > 0} ]
(*-((E^(-(x^2/(4 a t))) Sqrt[a t] \[Alpha] (qp0 + \[Alpha] \[Theta]air))/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] \[Lambda]^2))*)
```

because `E^(-(x^2/(4 a t)))` decreases with x!

The boundary condition u[x,0]==0 can be verified(a>0,x>0):

```
Simplify[Limit[u[x, t] /. sol[[1]], t -> 0], {x > 0, a > 0}]
(* 0 *)
```

but the solution doesn't fullfill the pde

```
(E^(-(x^2/(4 a t))) Sqrt[a t] \[Alpha] (qp0 + \[Alpha] \[Theta]air))/\[Lambda] == 0
```

Also ic2 isn't true!

Comment: Sadly it's not… you'll see the 2nd graph in the question if you plot it.

Comment: @xzczd hopefully it does. I edited my answer...

Comment: Well, but it doesn't satisfy the b.c. at $x=0$, try `test = {u[x, 
      t] -> -((\[Alpha] (qp0 + \[Alpha] \[Theta]air) ((2 \[Alpha] + x \[Lambda]) Erfc[x/(
           2 Sqrt[a t])] - 
         2 E^((\[Lambda] (x \[Alpha] + a t \[Lambda]))/\[Alpha]^2) \[Alpha] Erfc[(
           x \[Alpha] + 2 a t \[Lambda])/(2 Sqrt[a t] \[Alpha])]))/(
      2 \[Lambda]^3))} /. (u[x, t] -> rest_) :> (u -> Function @@ {{x, t}, rest});
Simplify[ic2 /. test, t > 0]`. You can also plot the solution and compare it to the graph in the question.

Comment: @xzczd `u[x,0}==0` !I edited my answer...

Comment: This is the initial condition… I mean the boundary condition i.e. `ic2` in the code.

Comment: @xzczd You're right, thanks or your hint. Obviously the analytical MMA-solution isn't true.