# Transform expression involving Erfc back and forth with Laplace transform and its inversion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, integral-transforms

It's a problem I encountered when answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163870/1871) and I think it's worth starting a new question for it. Consider the following expressions:

```
expr = Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[t])] - E^(t + x) Erfc[Sqrt[t] + x/(2 Sqrt[t])];
texpr = E^(-Sqrt[s] x)/(s + s^(3/2));
```

`texpr` is the Laplace transform of `expr` when `x > 0`. This can be verified numerically:

```
With[{pre = 32}, 
 Block[{x = RandomReal[{0, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> pre], 
        s = RandomReal[{0, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> pre]}, 
  N[{texpr, NIntegrate[expr Exp[-s t], {t, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> pre]}, 
    pre/2 // Floor]]]
```

But `LaplaceTransform` and `InverseLaplaceTransform` can't handle them well:

```
LaplaceTransform[expr, t, s]
(* Partly unevaluated *)
InverseLaplaceTransform[texpr, s, t]
(* Unevaluated *)
```

My question is, can we transform `expr` to `texpr`, and `texpr` to `expr` with some extra coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `texpr` to `expr`.
We can use:

```
texpr = E^(-Sqrt[s] x)/(s + s^(3/2));
s1 = LaplaceTransform[texpr, x, a] // Apart
s2 = InverseLaplaceTransform[s1, s, t] // Expand
InverseLaplaceTransform[s2[[1]], a, x] // FullSimplify
```

> $$\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)-e^{t+x} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{2 t+x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)$$

For `expr` to `texpr`:

```
expr = Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[t])] - E^(t + x) Erfc[Sqrt[t] + x/(2 Sqrt[t])];
ss1 = Assuming[{x > 0, t > 0}, LaplaceTransform[expr, x, a]] // Simplify // Expand
ss2 = LaplaceTransform[ss1, t, s]
Assuming[{a > 0, s > 0}, InverseLaplaceTransform[ss2, a, x] // Simplify]
```

> $$\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{s^{3/2}+s}$$

**Edited:**

For `expr` to `texpr`.The key is `Assuming command`:

Let:

```
 expr = Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[t])] - E^(t + x) Erfc[Sqrt[t] + x/(2 Sqrt[t])];
 LaplaceTransform[expr, t, s]
```

dosen't work ?,but with `Assuming`:

```
 expr = Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[t])] - E^(t + x) Erfc[Sqrt[t] + x/(2 Sqrt[t])];
 Assuming[{x > 0, t > 0}, LaplaceTransform[expr, t, s]] // FullSimplify

 (* E^(-Sqrt[s] x)/(s + s^(3/2)) *)
```