# Convolution using the Laplace integral transform of certain functions

Tags: symbolic, integral-transforms

I am trying to convolve two functions:

$f(t) = e^{- t}$

$g(t) = e^{-(e^{-t})^2}$

$(f*g)(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d\tau = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-(t-\tau)} e^{-(e^{-\tau})^2} d\tau$

Using the convolution property, we can transform it into a product of folding functions, each of which is obtained using the direct Laplace transform of each of the original functions, i.e.:

$(f*g)(t) \rightarrow L^{-1}(L(f(t)) \cdot L(g(t)))$

But it is known that the original functions must meet certain requirements.

With these functions, the Laplace transform will look like:

```
ut = Exp[-Exp[-t]^2]
LaplaceTransform[ut, t, s] LaplaceTransform[Exp[-t], t, s]
```

And this is result:

$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2},1\right)}{2 s+2}$

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(Gamma[s/2] - Gamma[s/2, 1])/(
     2 + 2 s), s, t]

Out[85]= InverseLaplaceTransform[(Gamma[s/2] - Gamma[s/2, 1])/(
 2 + 2 s), s, t]
```

But the inverse Laplace transform of this function does not work. What could be the reason and are there any ways to find the inverse Laplace transform of this function?

I will be glad to any advice and help.

Comment: "Unfortunately, neither Mathematica nor Maple mastered this integral. " `Integrate` gives the result within 2 seconds, how do you code it?: `f[t_] = E^-t;
g[t_] = Exp[-Exp[-t]^2];
AbsoluteTiming[Integrate[f[t - \[Tau]] g[\[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}]]`

Comment: I fixed it. The main problem is with the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: I want to note that the integral is not calculated if you select the function `Exp[-2 t]`

Comment: Not too surprsing. Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163949/1871 Sadly the method there doesn't work for this problem.

Comment: A workaround: `f2[t_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[-Gamma[s/2, 1], s, t]; 
g2[t_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(2 s + 2), s, t]; 
Integrate[f2[t - \[Tau]]*g2[\[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}] // FullSimplify`